Are we on our last legs?
Folks, we need candidates to step up for a position as Moderator.
I CANNOT keep doing this on my own, as I have been for a long while. Burnout is real, and I don't think the site should suffer because of one person.
The job is very easy, but falls short of being the top of my priority list in life.
If Stack Exchange does not get qualified candidates to run in the election, there is a very real chance that Freelancing.SE will be shut down.
So please, put your name forward if asked. Participate with flags for content that shouldn't be here. Ask and answer more questions to help the site succeed!

SpencerG is aware that I've volunteered to moderate single handedly while you take a well deserved vacation. I already moderate elsewhere but don't mind twice the work, which is minimal with inactive sites. I'm surprised that he hasn't discussed this with you.

Network Flair (clickable image)

No one has told me that there is anyone willing to take over the moderation, or help out - just that elections have been held and no candidates stepping up.
